# why is my page opened by ie8 with ie7 interpreter as standard?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Hi i have made a website. And cause of some crazy reason i don't figure out the ie8 runs it with Browsermode: i8  and Documentmode: ie7 (standard). Why he doesn't use ie8 for both?

Answer (score 3):

Did you put a valid DOCTYPE into your pages? Otherwise IE8 will run in compatibility mode.

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikeormond/archive/2008/09/25/ie-8-compatibility-meta-tags-http-headers-user-agent-strings-etc-etc.aspx) for details.